# Split and sequentially join string parts in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, split

I need to create a DB view with parts of sequential combinations of string parts of a source column. Example:

IN:

```
tag
--------
A_B_C_D
X_Y_Z
```

OUT:

```
subtag
--------
A
A_B
A_B_C
A_B_C_D
X
X_Y
X_Y_Z
```

The answer seems to be somewhere around [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), but I cannot put it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @laurenz-albe! There is a problem with your code that it's missing recursion break condition. So I ended up with this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE s AS (
   SELECT tag FROM tag
UNION
   SELECT regexp_replace(tag, '_[^_]*$', '') 
   FROM s
   WHERE tag LIKE '%\_%'
)
SELECT * FROM s;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c8eb97e9d0a8fe38a838135008d5d24f)

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=590163137f7f117080dbdb3d5bed3e16)

```
SELECT
    array_to_string(                                                    -- 3
        array_agg(t.value) OVER (PARTITION BY tags ORDER BY t.number),   --2
        '_'
    ) AS subtag
FROM
    tags,
    regexp_split_to_table(tag, '_') WITH ORDINALITY as t(value, number)  -- 1
```

1. Split the string into one row per element. The `WITH ORDINALITY` adds a row count which can be used to hold the original order of the elements
2. Using `array_agg()` window function to aggregate the elements. The `ORDER BY` makes it cumulative
3. Reaggregate the array into a string.

Comment: Typically `unnest(string_to_array(...))` is faster than `regexp_split_to_table()` if no regex is needed to split a string

Comment: Thank you @s-man. [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) approach works much faster on a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE s AS (
   SELECT tag FROM tag
UNION
   SELECT regexp_replace(tag, '_[^_]*$', '') FROM s
)
SELECT * FROM s;

   tag   
---------
 A_B_C_D
 X_Y_Z
 A_B_C
 X_Y
 A_B
 X
 A
(7 rows)
```

The idea is to successively cut off `_*` at the end.